# Widget in Qt: Change background-color onclick

Tags: c++, qt

I want to make a realy simple thing, but I am new to c++ and Qt.

On click on some widget I want to change background color of this clicked widget and background of another widget with specific name. Widgets don't have got onclick(). I thing I have to use something different like mousePressEvent, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am new to c++ and Qt.

You should probably start with working through a Qt book like [C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160).

> Widgets don't have got onclick(). I thing I have to use something different like mousePressEvent

Yes, for your particular issue, you can override the [QWidget::mousePressEvent()](http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/qt4-doc-html/html/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) method:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
...
protected:
    void mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event );
}
```

```
void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event ) {
    // do whatever you want when the mouse button is clicked, e.g. 
    // modify the palette of the widget to change the background color
}
```

Here is a sample application (an Icon editor) which does something similar: http://files.itslearning.com/data/764/2405/qt4/ch05lev1sec2.html

Comment: Thanks, but can I ask you how can I connect my widget created in designer to class please?

Comment: In Designer, take a `QWidget`, and then **promote** it to your custom widget. See http://www.tinesoft.com/qt/use-custom-widgets-with-qt-designer-promotion-technique for a complete example.

Comment: Danke schön you are lifesaver